# Column 'VacationsTable.StartDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure that the user inputs a month in the Textbox and presses the button, the user is presented with the data of average price per night for for all the cities in the vacations database.
For Example:
Amsterdam: 134.44
and when the startdate is in the same month as the input and the enddate is not to calculate only th days in the month that the user inputs and vise versa for the enddate

this is mt procedure :

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_AdminAvgPriceMonth
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @month int
AS
BEGIN

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select case 
                when month(StartDate)= @month and month(EndDate)=@month
                then avg(datediff(day, StartDate, EndDate)*price)
                when month(StartDate)=@month and month(EndDate)<>@month
                then avg(datediff(day, StartDate, EOMONTH(StartDate))*price)
                     --month(StartDate)<>@month and month(EndDate)=@month 
                else avg(datediff(day, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, StartDate), 0), EndDate)*price)
                end as avrgPrice
    from VacationsTable VT inner join FlatsTable FT on VT.FlatId=FT.FlatId
    group by City
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked your logic, but you will likely need to move your `CASE` statements inside your `AVG()` statements... It is like the error message explains, that `StartDate` is not inside your aggregates. Try structuring like below

```
select avg( case  
            when month(StartDate)= @month and month(EndDate)=@month
            then (datediff(day, StartDate, EndDate)*price) --etc
```

And then check your logic if you get no further errors.

Sometimes, I find it is helpful to use a subquery, CTE, or temporary table result to separate your business formula logic from your report aggregation logic. So consider that, as well if it helps.